# Realtime communication between 2 files

Tags: vba, excel

We have "host.xlsb" and "checkin.xlsb" on PC#1.

PC#2 open "checkin" via lan.

In business hour, clients will come and scan their membership ID card's bar code using bar code scanner.

Bar code scanner reads the ID and send to "checkin".

"checkin" checks the ID and display info (eg. which table) to clients, and record the ID and the check in time to a list.

"host" is for reception, pull data from "checkin" to see who has come and who has not and check if clients went to wrong table.

Thus I want "host" could read changes on "checkin" in realtime, possible?

P.S.:

I know I can do it if I simply put "host" and "checkin" in a single workbook and use PC#1 only.

But if I combine them, I will need reception to wait for clients or clients to wait for reception.

Neither I don't want any other PC to open the combined one at the same time.

Comment: Your description is unclear.  Clients scan their ID into "host"?  Just before that you say they use "echo"...

Comment: Why not use Access Database as back end and Access/Excel as front end for this? Excel is not Apt for this.

Answer (score 0):

Make the application at the checkin machine keep the data in a seperate (ASCII) file. Checkin would open the file with write access and update the information. The "host" machine would open the file with read access and check the latest info, then close the file.